# Numerous xml errors when trying to make a custom editText style xml

Tags: android, xml

Desperately trying to create a simple style for my edit text box, this is infuriating me to no end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
andoid:color="#44433A" />
<solid android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

I get two errors, "Error Parsing XML: unbound prefix" at "stroke"   and another at "android:color" "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

Now I have a feeling at least one of them has to do with the xmlns etc and the address (of which I have no idea about but would love to know).

Comment: have you tried my edited xml.Hopes its work if it did please accept answer.Highly appreciated.help us by accepting the answer by clicking tick mark below down arrow.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#44433A" />

    <solid android:color="#FFF" />

</shape>
```

spelling of android in stroke color is wrong on your code everything else works my side.